# Em consultas SQL devo seguir a ordem do índice?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, índices

Se na minha tabela X for criado um índice com os campos A, B e C (nesta ordem), nas consultas SQL devo seguir exatamente essa ordem?

Exemplo seguindo a ordem do índice:

```
SELECT * FROM X
 WHERE X.A = VALOR_A
   AND X.B = VALOR_B
   AND X.C = VALOR_C
```

Exemplo sem seguir a ordem do índice:

```
SELECT * FROM X
 WHERE X.C = VALOR_C
   AND X.A = VALOR_A
   AND X.B = VALOR_B
```

Em questão de performance e rapidez de leitura, as duas consultas acima teriam o mesmo resultado?

Comment: No caso teria os mesmos resultados em questão de performance e resultados dos dados, a ordem nesse caso não importaria.

Comment: Em teoria, tanto faz. Na prática, depende como o engine que processa o SQL foi feito. É de se esperar que as duas consultas sejam equivalentes. Para ter certeza, só lendo a documentação do engine usado. O SQL não é processado como texto, ele passa usualmente por um _query planner_ que tenta otimizar da melhor maneira possível, então situações óbvias normalmente são equivalentes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não, a ordem na qual você constroi a expressão do seu `WHERE` não influencia na performance (ou não deveria).

Qualquer `RDBMS` que se preze é capaz de analisar o plano da *query* que está em execução a fim de se determinar a melhor maneira de se filtrar os dados.

O padrão `ANSI SQL` diz o seguinte:

> **6.3.3.3 Rule evaluation order**
>
> [...]
>
> Where the precedence is not determined by the Formats or by parentheses,
>   effective evaluation of expressions is generally
>   performed from left to right. However, it is implementation-dependent
>   whether expressions are actually evaluated left to right, particularly
>   when operands or operators might cause conditions to be raised or if
>   the results of the expressions can be determined without completely
>   evaluating all parts of the expression.

[Referência](http://grigoras.perso.enseeiht.fr/ens/bd/5WD-02-Foundation-2003-09.pdf)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Você foi direto ao ponto e disse que "não". Na outra resposta disseram que "depende". Ainda estou em dúvida.

Comment: @electus O único jeito de saber com certeza absoluta se afeta a performance é (por mais óbvio que possa parecer) fazendo testes de performance. Dependendo da query, dos dados, do software e até do hardware, pode fazer diferença ou não, mas você só vai saber testando, cada caso é um caso. Mas antes eu voltaria um passo: atualmente isso está gerando um problema de performance? Se não estiver, eu nem me preocuparia com isso, pra começar...

Comment: @electus Se for por falta de NÃO: Não, não e não. Você pode dar esta resposta como a correta. O motor do Sistema de Gerenciamento de Banco de Dados Relacional (RDBMS) não será afetado pela ordem dos campos na query, no order by, ordem dos inner joins, etc. Ele foi construido no intuito de abstrair todas essas coisas p/ você. Embora em teoria alguém poderia construir um RDBMS assim esse seria um tão pobre que ninguém o usaria.

Comment: Se vc começar a estudar como esses sistemas funcionam na prática vai ver que isso não é algo com que se preocupar (embora vc vá descobrir que há milhares de outras coisas com o que se preocupar q vc nem faz idéia)

Answer (score 7):

Depende da implementação do banco de dados (nenhuma *mainstream* que eu saiba, a não ser por um improvável *bug*), na maioria não importa, ele vai achar a melhor forma de usar o índice, pelo menos nos casos mais simples como este. Em casos mais complexos pode não ocorrer a utilização adequada do índice nos DBs mais ingênuos. É verdade que "ordem" em casos mais complexos já seja um conceito complicado de definir.

Isto não vale para qualquer consulta, há situações que a ordem influenciará se ele pode ou não usar o índice para obter performance.

Geralmente deve-se criar os índices necessários para as consultas que você utiliza no código e de fato seja comprovado que há ganhos. Lembrando que a criação de um índice incorre em um custo extra, principalmente de escrita, mas também afeta leitura por ter mais dados para "sujar" o cache.

Sempre vale a máxima de que performance deve ser testada, muita coisa que vale aqui não vale ali, em banco de dados isto é mais verdadeiro porque até o volume e distribuição dos dados afeta se terá bom resultado ou não.

Comment: Você disse que depende da implementação do banco de dados e que na maioria não importa. Você teria como incrementar sua resposta mostrando quais bancos de dados a ordem do índice afeta a performance da consulta? Fiquei curioso.

Comment: Nenhum que eu conheça hoje em dia, pelo menos dos que são usados por muita gente.

Comment: Acha que daria pra testar se usa o índice através do ``EXPLAIN``? Aí faria a query dos dois modos e veria se usa o índice.

Comment: @CleberGriff sim, é uma técnica, para quem sabe interpretar o que ele mostra, embora num caso simples assim, deve ser fácil porque deve mostrar o mesmo.